# US Sewing Machine 120v 60Hz in the UK

Tags: voltage, frequency

[image]

I need some advice. Bought this sewing machine from Amazon US and I have it here in the UK. I am not worry about getting the step down voltage but how can I get the frequency up to 60Hz?
Some converters say 50Hz to 60Hz but I think that is just a range and not at all accurate.
The machine has never been used and I can't return it so I am stuck with it.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would a [VFC](vfc variable frequency controller) worth for the $8,000 to $30,000 machine? I had a friend using VFC for his yarn machine at an industrial setting. BTW, why is that sewing machine so expensive, Price of a car? I am tempted to make my own.

Comment: [VFC](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=vfc+variable+frequency+controller&ref=nb_sb_noss) at about $100, don't know the spec.

Comment: The motors in most sewing machines are not frequency sensitive. It will probably work without any problem once you have the voltage correct.

Comment: To be on a safe side I'd contact the manufacturer.

Comment: 99% chance the motor is brushed universal and it won’t care about frequency as long as the voltage is correct.

Comment: @winny & Kevin, That sewing machine is price of a car, more than my Honda van, h h.. I imagine the motor is not a free-run linear motor, nor an AC induction motor. May have a delicate BMW engine.

Comment: @jay Where did you get it from? I see such a model on amazon for ~$550

Comment: If it's an old one where 110V just drives a motor via a foot switch, it won't care about the frequency. If it's a fancy one with a CPU in it ... not sure about that.

Comment: If it is a fancy one with CPU control it is more likely to have a DC motor and not care about the AC input frequency(my wife has one like this). I have never heard of a sewing machine using induction motors they have traditionally used universal brushed motors.

Comment: @EugeneSh , Oh really, Dang.. Still better than mine, h h.. My wife made 20 masks at home at the very beginning of COVID, using an old Japanese sewing machine.

Comment: it's going to be a dc servo or stepper motor to do all those little custom stiches. the switch mode power supply won't care much about frequency as the first thing it does is rectify the mains anyway. If they cut corners choosing components it might, might, not have quite as much peak stall power (torque), but everything else should be indistinguishable.

Answer (score 1):

With my hacking skills, I was able to find a part list of 9985:

[9985 Parts List](http://www.europdistri.fr/download/vues/stylisttouch4085.pdf)

The EU and USA model differs in some important points:

- transformer
- power board

It is trivial that multi tap  transformer is adapted for different nominal voltage. Don't understand why power boards are different, since the motor is identical.

[Power board USA - 416401701](https://www.sewingpartsonline.com/power-circuit-unit-singer-416401701.aspx)

[image]

As you can see, there is a common mode choke at the input, a Graetz rectifier and probably a Triac for motor control. Perhaps the difference is just in the fuse rating.

IMO, try to use a step down transformer to 120VAC, nothing would go wrong. If it will properly work, it's an another question.

EDIT:

The diiference on the power board is that for EU market the fuse is 1.6A, while for US market is 3.5A. You see, when they put the appropriate fuse, they strike the other with a marker.

[image]

I won't be surprised if the transformer could be easily reverted as well.

[image]

If my assumtion is correct, then there shall be four wires for the primary winding (red wires). For US market, they wire two primary windings in parallel, while for EU market they wire them in series. It would make sense to use just one part and then configure it for the required marked, same as power board.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2funUFC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: the power board has a different fuse for EU, there may also be other differences (larger capacitor?)  Also there is a different terminal box (270 HP33089) and controller cord (270 HP33115)